# Vuejs call other component's method with parameter

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have two components, the first one is for uploading a file and the second one to Show a file. Inside my Upload Component I would like to call the Preview Component and add a Parameter so that a method inside the Preview Component uses a value which is created inside the Upload Component.

So far I have done this:

UploadComponent.vue

```
<template>
    …
    <button @click="upload"></button>
    <preview-component :url="this.location"></preview-component>
</template >

<script>
import PreviewComponent from '@/js/components/PreviewComponent';

export default {
    components: {
        'preview-component': PreviewComponent
    },

    props: ['url'],

    data () {
        return {
            // ...
            location: ''
        }
    },

    methods: {
        upload() {
            // ... upload stuff then update the global var location
            this.location = response.data.location;
        },
    }

}
</script>
```

This is my Preview Component:

```
<template>
    <div id="body">
        ///...
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['url'],

    methods: {
        loadPdf (url) {
            //
        },
    }    
}
</script>
```

So far I am getting the error that url is not defined, so it actually does not sent the url from the UploadCOmponent to the PreviewComponent, how do I manage to sent it?

Comment: parent component pass prop to child component with `:url="location"`, and in child component access prop in methods with `this.url`

Answer (score 0):

You got a ninja `this` in your `UploadComponent`'s template.

It should be `<preview-component :url="location"></preview-component>`

Comment: Hi thanks, but I still get this error `app.js:7989 [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "Error: Invalid parameter object: need either .data, .range or .url" app.js:9252 Error: Invalid parameter object: need either .data, .range or .url`

Comment: It seems it related to one of the extern component you're using. Not vue related